# Check if a node exist in XML using XPath in Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have different forms of XML that I must analyse,

```
<AMDI>
...
<MI>
</MI>
</AMDI>
```

or

```
<AMDI>
...
<AD>
</AD>
</AMDI>
```

So I want to build an XPath query depending of the type of the node (if it's an MI : XML_ITEMS = "//MI/DL/D", if it's an AD : XML_ITEMS = "//AD/DL/D")
I'm working with DocumentBuilder and XPathExpression.
Thnx for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also list the different nodes like this :

```
Node node = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList type = node.getChildNodes();
for(int i=0; i<nodes.getLength();i++)
     System.out.println(type.item(i).getNodeName();
```

And choose the write node :)
Thanx a lot

Comment: Above you write "nodes.getLength()", do you mean "type.getLength()"?

Answer (score 2):

**In XPath 1.0**:

```
//MI/DL/D  |   //AD/DL/D
```

**This is not syntactically legal in XPath 1.0**:

```
//(MI|AD)/DL/D
```

But you may use it in case you have an XPath 2.0 engine.

Comment: Thnx :) I should work more XPath, but just as a question, is XPath the best way to parse an XML Document ????

Comment: @taichimaro: XPath is the best way to *search* within an XML document. XPath works on XML documents that are already parsed by an XML parser.